# Yii2 API authentication Behaviors() Not working

Tags: api, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am creating restful api in yii2. Here I am facing a issue. 
In my userController.php I have created a behaviour() for authentication.

```
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;

public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
        'except' => ['signup']
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

Here I have passed `'except' => ['signup']`, So that authentication should be not applied to 'signup' action.

But here it is not applied and asking for authentication for 'signup' action too.

So, please guide where I have mistaken.

Comment: - You can try using another method for authorizing "HttpBearerAuth" as well as [the manual by Budi Irawan](http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/)
- Also can refer this project https://github.com/NguyenDuyPhong/yii2_advanced_api_phong (including database) - It's working very well on my localhost. Hopefully I helped you something!

Comment: if  'as beforeRequest' => [ 'class' => 'yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth'] is configured in application config, this issue will happen

Comment: In my case the problem was that `except` needed `my-action` instead of `myAction`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess files

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        [
            'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
            'except' => ['signup']
        ]
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

Comment: What did you change and why does it solve the problem?